# How extract information from my model on the handler in yesod?

Tags: entity, monads, yesod

my question is about how can I extract from a list of query result the year of each entity Post.

My model is this:

```
Post
    name Text
    content Text
    date UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    deriving Show
```

And my handler looks like this:

```
getYearR :: Integer -> Handler Html
getYearR year = do
    posts <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PostDate]
    years <- --some function with posts for extract the list of years
    defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Blog"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

Maybe the solution is related with some basic knowledge about monads but I don't know how that works for this situation.

Thanks for your time and I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I created a convenience function to extract the year. I referenced [these docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:UTCTime) on getting the `Day` from `UTCTime`, and [these docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.1.4/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html) on getting the year from the `Day`.

```
import Data.Time

getYear :: UTCTime -> Integer
getYear time = 
    let (year,_,_) = toGregorian $ utctDay time
    in year
```

Using this function, I can get a list of years by extracting the Haskell record from the `Entity` using [`entityVal`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.7/20131212-1/persistent/Database-Persist-Types.html#v:Entity), extract the `UTCTime` using `postDate`, then extract the year using my `getYear` function

```
let years = map (getYear . postDate . entityVal) posts
```

If you're using the list of years in Hamlet, you could skip creating the intermediate `years` value and just iterate through `posts`:

```
<ul>
    $forall Entity id post <- posts
        <li>
            <h4>The year is #{getYear $ postDate post}</a>
```